# How to install jdk 8 on ubuntu server 18.04?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install JDK 8 ON Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS, with the following commands:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

/usr/lib/jvm folder has:
[image]

I also set the path into /etc/environment for JAVA_HOME
But I still get an error while java -version as:

```
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre            
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Can anyone please suggest to solve an error?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "opemjdk-8-jdk"? Typo? Also [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Update alternatives for Java. This should fix the problem:

```
 update-alternatives --config java
```

Reference: https://linoxide.com/install-java-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you for the help, However it is not working, shows the message as below:    `update-alternatives: warning: /etc/alternatives/java is dangling; it will be updated with best choice
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java Nothing to configure`

Comment: Try adding: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
Reference: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/install-oracle-java-jdk-8-10-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
apt install oracle-java8-set-default
```

The above commands will automatically install selected java version and set all necessary java environment variables.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the solution, but I need JDK 8 and when I tried this command I got an error:  `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java8-set-default is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  oracle-java17-set-default oracle-java11-set-default-local

E: Package 'oracle-java8-set-default' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer, I mistakenly deleted default files i.e. java 11,

So I run following commands:

```
sudo apt purge -y openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt purge -y openjdk-8-jre-headless
sudo apt purge -y default-jdk
```

then I run command to set java 8 as default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and the version is correctly reflect..